# WADL with grammar for JSON representation

Tags: java, json, jaxb, jax-rs, cxf

I try to automatically generate a WADL with a grammar for my JAX-B objects with JSON representation, but it is not working completly.

**Code:**

JAX-B model class:

```
@XmlRootElement(namespace = "http://www.test.com/test")
@XmlAccessorType(value = XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class TestModel {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private String id;

    @XmlElement
    private String name;
}
```

JAX-RS resource class:

```
@Path("test")
public class TestResource {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void create(TestModel testModel) {
        // some code
    }
}
```

CXF configuration:

```xml
<jaxrs:server address="/rest/1" id="test" staticSubresourceResolution="true">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="testResource" /> 
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <bean class="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider" />
    </jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:server>
```

**WADL:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<application xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02">
    <grammars>
        <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.test.com/test" targetNamespace="http://www.test.com/test" elementFormDefault="unqualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
            <xs:import/>
            <xs:element type="testModel" name="testModel"/>
        </xs:schema>
        <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.test.com/test" targetNamespace="http://www.test.com/test" elementFormDefault="unqualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
            <xs:complexType name="testModel">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="id"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name" minOccurs="0"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:schema>
    </grammars>
    <resources base="http://localhost:8080/test-app/services/rest/1">
        <resource path="/test">
            <method name="POST">
                <request>
                    <representation mediaType="application/json"/>
                </request>
                <response status="204"/>
            </method>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</application>
```

The grammar is generated, but I'm missing the element reference, something like:

```xml
<representation mediaType="application/json" element="testModel"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [customizing of the WADL generation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jaxrs-services-description.html#JAXRSServicesDescription-CustomizingWADLGeneration) is neccessary. The property [`linkJsonToXmlSchema`](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest-3.0.x/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/model/wadl/WadlGenerator.html#setLinkJsonToXmlSchema(boolean)) of the [`WadlGenerator`](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest-3.0.x/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/model/wadl/WadlGenerator.html) adds the link.

CXF configuration:

```xml
<bean id="wadlGenerator" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.model.wadl.WadlGenerator">
    <property name="linkJsonToXmlSchema" value="true" />
</bean>

<jaxrs:server address="/rest/1" id="test" staticSubresourceResolution="true">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="testResource" /> 
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <bean class="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider" />
        <ref bean="wadlGenerator" />
    </jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:server>
```

See also: [CXF – Missing WADL method parameter element types with JSON JAX-RS services](http://www.devsumo.com/technotes/2015/01/cxf-missing-wadl-method-parameter-element-types-with-json-jax-rs-services/)

**Update:**

Since 3.1.x [`linkJsonToXmlSchema`](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest-3.1.x/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/model/wadl/WadlGenerator.html#setLinkJsonToXmlSchema(boolean)) is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing [Sergey Beryozkin](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/ViewProfile.jspa?name=sergey_beryozkin) at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-5479:

> In 3.0.1 "linkJsonToXmlSchema" has been deprecated so the plugin supports a new "linkAnyMediaTypeToXmlSchema",

so you should use:

```xml
<property name="linkAnyMediaTypeToXmlSchema" value="true" />
```

Comment: @Thanks, I will try it. If it works, I come back and upvote your answer.